# Reading the contents of a piped input file in Python program

Tags: python, stdin

I have to read the contents of text file that has been piped into the Python program. The file to the input file can be passed as follows

1. Your program must accept input from two sources: a filename passed in command line arguments and STDIN. For example, on Linux or OSX both `./myprogram input.txt` and `./myprogram < input.txt` should work.

I don't know how to do this.

```
if __name__ == '__main__': 
  # I don't know what to do here.
```

The input file has the following lines, and each line needs to be parsed.

```
Add Tom 4111111111111111 $1000
Add Lisa 5454545454545454 $3000
Add Quincy 1234567890123456 $2000
Charge Tom $500
Charge Tom $800
Charge Lisa $7
Credit Lisa $100
Credit Quincy $200
```

Whenever I try `python myprogram.py > input.txt`, then the program hangs. I am using Python 3.6.5 if that helps.

Update:

I tried something along these lines:

```
(env) myproject (master) $ python main.py > test.txt
testing testing testing
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

The file creates a new file if it does not exist, or overwrites the existing file with the entered contents. In this case, a new file called `test.txt` was created with the above contents.

Update # 2

I tried something like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  for line in sys.stdin.readline():
      print (line)
```

For a single line like this

```
Add Tom 4111111111111111 $1000
```

Each character is shown in a new line as in

```
A
d
d

T
o
m

. . .
```

I want all characters to be printed on a single line.

Comment: Note that `<` and `>` have different meanings in the shell. `<` redirects standard input, `>` redirects standard output. By doing `python myprogram.py > input.txt`, you are getting the shell to redirect the output of the python script to the file `input.txt`. If your program doesn't print anything, it would create an empty file. It will also overwrite any existing contents of the file.

Comment: `python myprogram.py < input.txt > out.txt` reads from input.txt and writes to out.txt

Comment: @AdamBurke I have updated my post with my findings.

Comment: You've got characters into a variable called `line` now ... you would have to do something with them, perhaps by passing them to functions and other operations, before you pass what you want to be output to `print()`. Maybe have a go at writing a `parse()` function next.

Comment: On the stdin / stdout part specifically, note that they are both file-like objects in python. So you can usually look at the number of parameters passed, and use that to work out whether to use a filename or stdin, then pass that along, much as @john-gordon says

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv` is a list that holds the arguments (if any) that your program was called with.

If it is one element long, then your program was called without any arguments (the script name itself is the first argument, so it doesn't really count), and therefore you should read from `sys.stdin`.

Otherwise if it has two or more elements, your program was called with a filename as an argument, so you should open that file and use it as the input.

Answer (score 0):

This worked the best for me. https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html

> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:], defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty

After a bit of trial and error, this is what I came up with

```
def handle_command_line_inputs():
    """Read the contents of the file piped through the command line.

    Once the operations are executed, then the balance is ready to be displayed
    """
    logging.info('Reading from the file')
    for line in fileinput.input():
        print(line)
        # My custom logic
```

This prints each line.

In my unit test

```
from unittest import mock


def get_test_file():
    current_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    return os.path.normpath(os.path.join(current_path, 'input.txt'))


def read_input_file():
    """Simulates the generators that read file contents."""
    input_file = get_test_file()
    with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line


@mock.patch('fileinput.input', side_effect=read_input_file)
def test_handle_command_line_inputs(mocked_fileinput):

    myprogram.handle_command_line_inputs()
    # Run your assertions.
```